# specific mysql query for game application

Tags: mysql

This is for a game I'm developing.
I have a MySQL table with each player entity that contains the id of the weapon they hold in each hand for example:

```
player id, playername, rhand, lhand,
1          Guy         1      2
2          OtherGuy    3      2
```

and I have an items table containing information about each item by id

```
item  name   damage_type
1     hammer crush
2     shield none
3     sword  slash
```

when resolving combat on my server I search for each player by id one is the attacker and one is the defender  I would like to return a result with each players weapon name and perhaps a property of the weapon (i.e. damage_type above) on the same line so I'd like results like this

```
player id playername rhand lhand   rhand_damage_type lhand_damage_type
1         Guy        hammer shield crush             none
2         OtherGuy   sword  shield slash             none
```

Comment: SELECT *  FROM game_moblist LEFT JOIN items ON (rhand=items.id) LEFT JOIN items ON (lhand=items.id) WHERE 1 

This didn't work because im using the same alias for left and right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.player_id, p.player_name, w1.name, w2.name, w1.damage_type, w2.damage_type 
FROM players p, weapons w1, weapons w2 
WHERE p.player_id = attackerId OR p.player_id=defenderId
AND p.rhand = w1.item 
AND p.lhand = w2.item
```

In case the plyers might also miss one or both weapons:

```
SELECT DISTINCT player_id, player_name, w1.name, w2.name, w1.damage_type, w2.damage_type 
FROM 
(SELECT player_id, player_name, name, damage_type 
 FROM players LEFT JOIN weapons on rhand = w1.item 
 WHERE p.player_id = attackerId OR p.player_id=defenderId) as w1,
(SELECT player_id, player_name, name, damage_type 
 FROM players LEFT JOIN weapons on lhand = w2.item 
 WHERE p.player_id = attackerId OR p.player_id=defenderId) as w2
 Were w1.player_id = w2.player_id
```

Comment: I got empty results I might have done it wrong.  I was thinking the solution would be a left join on rhand=item.id and a second left join on lhand=item.id but using alias and I don't know the syntax well enough to do that.